# Is Luke's hand animatronic or CG?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, luke-skywalker, special-effects, cgi

I am referring to the appearance in *The Force Awakens*

> [image]

Comment: I'm thinking CGI. I doubt they'd make a famous actor like Hamill bother with animatronics, especially since his part was so limited in the film.

Comment: @RedCaio you never know though. Prosthetics is an old part of the acting repertoire, if not ancient. It's probably not as expensive as we may think.

Comment: It appears CG, but very well could be prosthetic. I know Rey's amazing appearing muffin looked like CG, but actually was a physical prop... JJ had a crew of very old-school prop designers working on the thing, so it wouldn't surprise me if it was a prop.

Comment: (Does anyone else think this looks like his arms were transplanted and they now come out of his ribcage?)

Comment: @Vogie: [something, something] Rey's amazing muffin

Comment: I don't understand why the image is in a spoiler, when it's flat-out said he appears in the title/question and he's had a fake hand since the events of ESB.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Simon Pegg](http://www.outerplaces.com/science-fiction/item/10526-simon-pegg-reveals-the-owner-of-the-robotic-hand-from-the-star-wars-the-force-awakens-trailer), the hand seen in the trailer (and in the film) was  a prop and *wasn't* added in later with CGI.

> "I am on set as a consultant, acting as a sounding board for J.J., who
>   is making tweaks to the already wonderful screenplay. My computer is
>   open in Final Draft and, at the top of my screen, the scene heading
>   reads, "INT. S-REDACTED-R – Day". I hear a familiar voice and turn to
>   see Mark walking onto set, looking trim and cool, with a beard that he
>   grumbles about but makes him look handsome and Jedi-like. **When they
>   shot Luke placing his robotic hand on R2's head, a moment glimpsed in
>   the trailer, I sat at the monitors with Mark's family and marvelled at
>   the huge significance of the moment.**

Clearly they couldn't have shot him (live) putting his robotic hand on to the R2-D2 model if it wasn't a real/practical prop. Whether it was animatronic (or not) remains to be seen.

[image]

Comment: Couldn't they have just painted his hand green or have him wear a green glove?

Comment: @CreationEdge - Oh, very possibly. My feeling was that *"When they shot Luke **placing his robotic hand** on R2's head*" is pretty conclusive though. When they finally release the 'Making-of" documentary, I'll make an effort to update this post.

Comment: Yeah, it's just hard to say if he meant for us to know which seen he meant, post-editing, or if he actually saw the hand then and there. (I'm not meaning to detract from this answer. Just wondering.)

Comment: @CreationEdge - I don't really see how you could read it any other way than that he was sitting in the trailer watching a live feed from the set, of Luke putting his robot hand onto R2-D2.. Try it without all the unnecessary commentary *"*When they shot Luke placing his robotic hand on R2's head...I sat at the monitors with Mark's family and marvelled..."*

Comment: If he said "Luke putting his green hand that ended up being edited into his robot hand in post", it wouldn't have the same impact in retelling!

Comment: The hand doesn't appear to be the same as later in the movie anyway. I could see them using a glove or simple sub-in for this one, but the one during the hood removal is just *off*.

Answer (score 2):

A friend of my cousin, Ryan Bradbury, told him that the prop team were never commissioned to make a hand for Luke, after my cousin asked about the lightsabers. Ryan Bradbury was (might still be for the next movie, didn't ask him) the prop production manager for The Force Awakens, and knows exactly which items were used and if the animatronics team were commissioned to build or program something. He said Luke's hand was not at all on the list, so it must be CGI.

Comment: Get him to post it somewhere you can link to.

Comment: Ok, sure, let me contact my cousin.

Comment: Did you get it done?